# Display rows after evaluating DATEDIFF mysql, python and pyqt5

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I have a table where i am storing the serial number, refill date and due date of lpg's, now i am trying to flag the gases that haven't been returned for refilling by using the DATEDIFF mysql function to subtract the CURDATE() from due date and if the value is greater than 0 i want to display it. But this is not working. Here is sample code:

```
def flag_item(self):
    try:
        dbname = self.ui.lineEdit_database_name_flag.text()
        password = self.ui.lineEdit_password_flag.text()
        table_name = self.ui.lineEdit_table_name_flag.text()

        db = mc.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password=password,
            database=dbname
        )

        dbcursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
        dbcursor.execute(f"SELECT due_date FROM {table_name}")
        # result_1 = dbcursor.fetchall()

        for x in dbcursor:
            print(x)

            dbcursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '{x}') > 0")
            result = dbcursor.fetchall()

            self.ui.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(0)

            for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
                self.ui.tableWidget_2.insertRow(row_number)

                for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                    self.ui.tableWidget_2.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

            print("Data Fetched")

    except mc.Error as e:
        print(f" Error: {e.msg}")
```

Print(x) prints only the first column but doesn't print other dates.
How do i go about rendering all columns that have exceeded the days.

Comment: Are you sure that ``for x in dbcursor`` is the correct way to iterate through all the columns?

Comment: is there another way?

Comment: My guess is you supposed to do `for x in result_1`. You already commented out `result_1`

Comment: This still does not populate the table

Comment: ok, but what do you get for print(x)